# Thread-safe list or concat multiple lists?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

I have two lists of dictionaries. I will query one user per Thread, up to a total of 50 users/threads.

The first list, "users", contains only one entry per thread.
The second list, "items", may contain thousands of entries per thread (300 is a good average).

At the moment, I query for users sequentially in a single thread: First, the data for one user is collected (this is implemented synchronously and includes ~100ms of plain waiting), then user will be added to "users", and then every item will be processed, one at a time, and added to "items" (processing takes around a dozen milliseconds for 1000 items).

While the lists are ordered, I don't have to preserve any order at all.

I now thought as follows:

- The first list is a good place for a ConcurrentBag.
- For the second list it is better to use multiple lists, one per thread, which are concat'ed together in the end.

But before I proceed like this, I'd like to ask you whether this is the best approach, or whether you can think of better solutions. In the to-be-parallelized part, I will do nothing on either list but Add items.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you query one user per thread? Without knowing the setup/design of the application it seems like a lot of threading for no reason other than to be multithreaded.

Comment: @Joeb454 The design of the original API (from other vendor) that we query allows to request only one user per call, since each user's data may be stored on a different endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this [Thread-Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx) article, any collection in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace (which includes `ConcurrentBag`) should be fine for your multi-threading needs.

I can say from experience that using `lock` around a simple `Dictionary` (in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace) worked fine for a huge in-memory, add-only collection. In production, it regularly held millions of items with no issues, even with a periodic process to spin through and remove "expired" items.

So bottom line, you shouldn't need to resort to building 50 separate lists for the items and then concatenate them afterward. But of course, that approach would probably work just fine too. It may just come down to whatever you personally find to be the most convenient.